# reading a .tif file in R

Tags: r

I am reading a .tif file in R and getting 4 warnings messages listed below. When I follow the instruction on the 4th message, the first 3 warnings still remain but the values read from file changes drastically at every pixel. Please help me in reading the data correctly from the .tif files. Sample File can be found on the link: **ftp://ftp.ntsg.umt.edu/pub/MODIS/NTSG_Products/MOD16/MOD16A2_MONTHLY.MERRA_GMAO_1kmALB/GEOTIFF_0.05degree/**

my code:

```
remove(list=ls()) 

library(tiff)

library(raster)

str_name<-'MOD16A2_ET_0.05deg_GEO_2008M01.tif' 

read_file<-readTIFF(str_name)
```

Warning messages:

```
1: In readTIFF(str_name) :
  TIFFReadDirectory: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered
2: In readTIFF(str_name) :
  TIFFReadDirectory: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered
3: In readTIFF(str_name) :
  TIFFReadDirectory: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered
4: In readTIFF(str_name) :
  tiff package currently only supports unsigned integer or float sample formats in direct mode, but the image contains signed integer format - it will be treated as unsigned (use native=TRUE or convert=TRUE to avoid this issue)
```

Please help me with this issue of reading tif files correctly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

Did you try simply the raster package raster function (or stack if multiple layered tif)? The raster package was made to deal with geo-referenced raster datasets:

```
library(raster)
str_name<-'MOD16A2_ET_0.05deg_GEO_2008M01.tif' 
imported_raster=raster(str_name)
```

The simple code above works and yields a raster object with the following properties:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 2800, 7200, 20160000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.05, 0.05  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -60, 80  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\lfortini\Downloads\MOD16A2_ET_0.05deg_GEO_2000M01.tif 
names       : MOD16A2_ET_0.05deg_GEO_2000M01 
values      : -32768, 32767  (min, max)
```

Comment: Hi, I used the commands but am getting following error message:Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create RasterLayer object from this file; perhaps you need to install rgdal first

Comment: my R version is: 2.15.2, if that helps in resolving the issue. When I load raster package it gives me the warning message:              Loading required package: sp
Warning messages:
1: package ‘raster’ was built under R version 2.15.3 
2: package ‘sp’ was built under R version 2.15.3

Comment: perhaps you need to install rgdal first

Comment: Hi, it may sound weird but yesterday I tried installing rgdal package in my laptop and it didn't install rather displayed error messages. Today, on my work place I was able to install rgdal package and code is running correctly. Big Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

Simply read the pixels as unsigned and convert them to signed:

```
 t = readTIFF("MOD16A2_ET_0.05deg_GEO_2008M01.tif", as.is=TRUE)
 t[t >= 32738L] = -65536L + t[t >= 32738L]
```

Looking at the image, you may also want to convert -32768 to `NA` as that seems to be the use in the file:

```
 t[t == -32768L] = NA
```

If you want to convert the integers to [-1,1] reals now, just do

```
 t = t / 32768
```

The first three warnings are just telling you that there are additional custom tags in the file.

Comment: Hi Simon, your method seems to read values correctly through first two lines; only issue is the values are 1 more than other approach of using raster function to read tif files and converting them to matrix. for e.g. if the other method shows value 199 at [650,1200], your method gives 200; otherwise it appears correct. Thanks.